# group by case condition followed by union of two columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following columns in table Sales :

```
Category1,priceA,priceB,Category2,costA,costB,type.(some items in category1 are same as category2)

sum(priceA), sum(priceB)
```

are to be grouped by category1,type.

```
sum(costA), sum(costB)
```

are to be grouped by category2,type.

I need the final output as

Union(category1,category2) as category3 ,sum(priceA)+sum(costA),sum(priceB)+sum(costB),type
to be grouped by UNION(category1+category2),type.

(sum(priceA)+sum(costA) would happen whenever items in category1 matches with category2 and same would be for sum(priceB)+sum(costB))

I tried to do it by

```
select category1,sum(priceA),sum(priceB),type group by category1,type
UNION ALL
select category2,sum(costA),sum(costB),type group by category2,type
```

Then following it up with another sum and group by. But I want to know how to do it without separately selecting and avoiding the union of basically 2 tables. Can I use group by followed by case statement here? Actually the table I referred as sales is an inner join of multiple tables , hence the motivation to not use select on it separately on two occasaions( in my actual case it would be union of 4 select queries on the table which makes the query look really big too). Plus I dont have permission to create procedure so no PL/SQL. Any fancy way for the above situation which will shorten the query and improve the performance ?

EDIT- SAMPLE DATA (Category1,PriceA,PriceB,Category2,CostA,CostB,Type)

```
+-----+----+----+-----+----+----+---+
| AUS | 20 | 25 | UK  | 35 | 40 | X |
| UK  | 30 | 26 | SA  | 32 | 40 | Y |
| USA | 22 | 24 | NZ  | 38 | 36 | Z |
| BRA | 16 | 10 | USA | 25 | 25 | Z |
| RUS | 20 | 15 | UK  | 20 | 30 | X |
+-----+----+----+-----+----+----+---+
```

Which I divided into union of two tables as these:

```
+-----+----+----+---+
| AUS | 20 | 25 | X |
| UK  | 30 | 26 | Y |
| USA | 22 | 24 | Z |
| BRA | 16 | 10 | Z |
| RUS | 20 | 15 | X |
+-----+----+----+---+
```

And

```
+-----+----+----+---+
| UK  | 55 | 70 | X |
| SA  | 33 | 40 | Y |
| NZ  | 38 | 36 | Z |
| USA | 25 | 25 | Z |
+-----+----+----+---+
```

Final output would be like :

```
+-----+----+----+---+
| UK  | 55 | 70 | X |
| UK  | 30 | 26 | Y |
| NZ  | 38 | 36 | Z |
| USA | 47 | 49 | Z |
| AUS | 20 | 25 | X |
| SA  | 32 | 40 | Y |
| BRA | 16 | 10 | Z |
| RUS | 20 | 15 | X |
+-----+----+----+---+
```

Comment: I really have no idea what you are trying to explain.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: So what's the problem here? To my eye it appears that the UNION ALL should work fine, but in your question you say "Actually the table I referred as sales is an inner join of multiple tables". How do you expect anyone to assist if you're not showing us what's really going on?  ???

Comment: @BobJarvis I edited with the sample data. The thing is the original table that I provided here is a reduced version obtained by doing multiple inner joins with six different tables which cannot be done without. So what I want is to use it just once and get the desired output. There must be some way to avoid union 4 times which makes the query really big and cumbersome

Comment: The usual way to do this would be to use a common table expression, also known as a "WITH" clause - but given that you need to do a UNION I'm not sure if that could be made to work here. The difficulty comes from not being able to see what your actual query is. In addition, your example code doesn't show a `FROM` clause, and your sample data doesn't show column names, making it very difficult to understand how the query and the sample data should be related.

Comment: Will unpivot work here to avoid UNION ?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you want. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/63b57/8).

```
with sample_data1 as (
  select "Category1", "PriceA", "PriceB", "Type"
    from sample_data
  union all
  select "Category2", "CostA", "CostB", "Type"
    from sample_data
)
select "Category1", sum("PriceA"), sum("PriceB")
from sample_data1 sd1
group by "Category1", "Type"
```

You will have to have a union at some point, because you need to increase the number of rows from your original source table. You can't do it with just a CASE.